# Sum $\sum_{r=1}^n \cos(2.(\frac {3^rx}{3})).\csc (3^rx)$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Prove that $$\sum_{r=1}^n \cos(2.(\frac {3^rx}{3})).\csc (3^rx) = \frac{1}{2\sin x}-\frac{1}{2\sin (3^nx)}$$

My attempt:
$$\Sigma \frac{\cos(\frac {2.3^rx}{3})}{\sin(3^rx)} = \Sigma \frac{1-2\sin^2(\frac {3^rx}{3})}{\sin(3^rx)}$$

I am trying to convert it to a form $f(r+1)-f(r)$ where $f(r)$ represents a general term in the series. But I am unable to do so.

Comment: hint: $\sin 3\theta = \sin\theta(2\cos 2\theta+1)\implies \frac1{\sin\theta} = \frac{1}{\sin3\theta} = ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1-2\sin^2(3^{r-1}x)}{\sin(3^rx)} &= \frac{1-2\sin^2(3^{r-1}x)}{\sin(3\cdot3^{r-1}x)} \\
&= \frac{1-2\sin^2(3^{r-1}x)}{3\sin(3^{r-1}x)-4\sin^3(3^{r-1}x)} \\
&= \frac{(3-4\sin^2(3^{r-1}x))-1}{2\sin(3^{r-1}x)\left(3-4\sin^2(3^{r-1}x)\right)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sin(3^{r-1}x)}-\frac{1}{2\sin(3\cdot3^{r-1}x)} \\
&= f(r-1)-f(r)
\end{align}